# Python добавление чисел в массив из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется Python 3.7.2
Имеется файл, в котором числа с плавающей запятой.
Нужно записать числа в массива, но не строками.
Пробовал применять int и float, также strip, чтобы убрать пробелы, но ничего не получается.
Можно ли вообще так сделать, а если можно ток как?
Код:

```
visits= []
with open(r"D:\pythonw\visits.txt","r") as test:
    for line in test:
        z=line.strip()
        x = int(z)
        visits.append(x)
```

Comment: А что именно не получается, какой текст ошибки? Покажите пример данных из файла?

Comment: не правильный литерал для int. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "1,3" , 1,3  -это первое число

Comment: Запятую, разделяющую целые, замените на точку.

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже был немаловажный факт)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без выкрутасов, то примерно так

```
with open(r"D:\pythonw\visits.txt","r") as test:
    for line in test:
        z = line.split() # разделяем числа в строке на отдельные элементы в списке
        for num in z:
            visits.append(float(num)) # вносим числа в итоговый список

print (visits)
```